Assigning classes to nodes in a graph to minimise intra-class distance
I have an complete undirected graph with n vertices, and the edge $(u,v)$ has weight   $d(u,v)$ for some distance function.
I also have $m<n$ elements, each of which belongs to a category $\{1...i\}$.
I wish to assign each element to a node such that the pairwise distance between all nodes in category $j$ is minimised, for all $j$.
Does any algorithm for such a problem exist, or is there any way of adapting an existing algorithm to solve this problem?
EDIT: my current idea is to formulate and solve the ILP. Any more intuitive ideas are greatly appreciated, as is insight into the complexity class of this problem. I feel it is NP-complete but I am unsure how to prove this.

The quantity you want to minimize is a bit unclear: is it the maximum distance between two nodes of the same category?

@Nathaniel ideally I would like to minimise the average distance between two nodes of the same category, but an algorithm for minimising maximum distance would also be very helpful.

Please don't use "EDIT:".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.  Please don't respond to requests for clarifications by  posting a comment -- instead, revise the post so it is clearer.  We want people to be able to understand what is being asked, without having to read the comments.  Thank you!

For the hardness proof, you can look into graph coloring (or its variants). Here's a possible hint:

 Try to show that the problem is hard, even when $d(u,v)=1~~ \forall (u,v)\in E$ and you want a perfect color.

Once you prove it is NP-hard, using ILP is not a bad idea. There are various techniques you can adopt to solve an ILP: branch-and-bound, heuristic, and rounding, to name a few. Modern ILP solvers (e.g., the Optimization Toolbox in MATLAB/Python, Gurobi, CPLEX, etc.) have gained significant edge in recent times.
You may want to look at these distance coloring articles  as well to design some suitable algorithms for your case: ref1, ref2.
